# Display the logged in username in Android exoplayer video

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to show the currently logged in username into the exoplayer video. I can display the username in a textview but can't place it into the player. It shows in the top of the player.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".PlayChannel">

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/exo_player_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/videoText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="216dp"
    android:text="@string/player_text"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/exo_player_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/videoText" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity:

```
    session = new SessionHandler(getApplicationContext());
    User user = session.getUserDetails();
    videoText.setText(user.getUsername());
    videoText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F5DC49"));
```

[Displaying output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDqvu.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/videoText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="Player Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/exo_edit_mode_background_color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/player_view" />
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. I want the text to be displayed in the player.

Comment: which layout have you used here?

Comment: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Comment: @nilimaakter Hope it helped